# 'str' object is not callable when looping defined code

Tags: python

I have this script that I am trying to do but I am getting an error message when I try to loop the defined code. I only have the recovered because it will be very long here. Also, I need help to put all my variables and be able to access it using notepad because I am using the idle version of python so that would be helpful!

```
def recovered():
    print("Recovered")
    print("China =",China_3)  
    print("India",India_3)
    print("USA =",USA_3)  
    print("Indonesia =",Indonesia_3) 
    print("Brazil =",Brazil_3)  
    print("Pakistan =",Pakistan_3)   
    print("Nigeria =",Nigeria_3)  
    print("Bangladesh =",Bangladesh_3)  
    print("Russia =",Russia_3) 
    print("Japan =",Japan_3)   
    print("Mexico =",Mexico_3)   
    print("Philippiness =",Philippines_)  
    print("Vietnam =",Vietnam_3)  
    print("Egypt =",Egypt_3)  
    print("Germany =",Germany_3)  
    print("Iran =",Iran_3)  
    print("Turkey =",Turkey_3)  
    print("Thiland =",Thailand_3)  
    print("France =",France_3) 
    print("United Kingdom =",United_Kingdom_3) 
    print("Italy =",Italy_3) 
    print("South Africa =",South_Africa_3)  
    print("South Korea =",South_Korea_3) 
    print("Columbia =",Colombia_3)  
    print("Spain =",Spain_3) 
    print("Ukraine =",Ukraine_3)  
    print("Kenya =",Kenya_3)   
    print("Argentina =",Argentina_3)  
    print("Poland =",Poland_3)  
    print("Sudan =",Sudan_3)  
    print("Uganda =",Uganda_3)  
    print("Canada =",Canada_3)  

    print("Now you are done with the tutorial, you will be able to explore your virus!")
    print("")
    print("""
    Here are the controls:
    1 = Cases
    2 = Deaths
    3 = Recovered
    4 = DNA points
    """)

def main():
    global DNA 
    global Smartness
    global cases
    global deaths
    global recovered
    print("Do your actions: ")
    main = input("")

  if main == "1":
      cases()
      print("")
      main()

  elif main == "2":
      deaths()
      print("")
      main()

  elif main == "3":
      recovered()
      print("")
      main()

  elif main == "4":
      DNA()
      print("")
      main()

  elif main == "5":
      Smartness()
      print("")
      main()

  else:
      print("Only chose a number between 1 and 5!")
      main()

  main()
```

Comment: You have a function with the name `main` and also a variable with the name `main` which is taking input, change any one of the names.

Comment: Oh, that's great thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def recovered():
    print("Recovered")

    countries = ["China",
                 "India"
                 # etc.
    ]

    # Updated, sample values and nested f-strings
    China_3 = 3
    India_3 = 5

    for country in countries:
        print(f"""{country} = {eval(f'{f"{country}_3"}')}""")

    print("Now you are done with the tutorial, you will be able to explore your virus!\n")
    print("""
    Here are the controls:
    1 = Cases
    2 = Deaths
    3 = Recovered
    4 = DNA points
    """)


def cases():
    pass


def deaths():
    pass


def dna():
    pass


def smartness():
    pass


def main():
    """Driver function."""
    global DNA
    global Smartness
    global cases
    global deaths
    global recovered
    print("Do your actions: ")
    choice = input("")

    if choice == "1":
        cases()
        print("")
        main()

    elif choice == "2":
        deaths()
        print("")
        main()

    elif choice == "3":
        recovered()
        print("")
        main()

    elif choice == "4":
        dna()
        print("")
        main()

    elif choice == "5":
        smartness()
        print("")
        main()

    else:
        print("Only chose a number between 1 and 5!")
        main()

main()
```

Comment: I want to get the variable to be seen with it again but when I tried running it it only came with the countries with _3

Comment: @Dylan I updated the for-loop over the countries to include a nested f-string which now also evaluates the country variables.